# Using ASP.NET Identity as backend for iOS / Android

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've got an ASP.NET SPA website (VS2013) that allows users to register (either locally or via Facebook) to use the site. The back end is ASP.NET web api. In the future, I'd like to consume the same web services from a native iOS app. Is there any way that I could validate a user's credentials and log them in from an iOS / Android login?

Comment: How do you authenticate user in web service right now(show some code)?

Comment: Everything is done through ASP.NET identity (2.0): AuthenticationManager.SignIn(...)